# Consequences of $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

$\{{a_n}\}$ is a sequence with $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)=1$.

I have trouble with these, so I want to verify these

(a) $a_n \leq1$ eventually; False

(b) $a_n \leq2$ eventually; True

(c) $a_n \geq1$ eventually; False

If any of these are wrong, could you please provide me with a counter-example so that I can verify it for myself? I'm afraid the "eventually" part is unclear to me.

Edit:

I actually intended for (c) to read $a_n \geq0$ eventually; False

Comment: This seems correct.

Comment: "$P(n)$ eventually" means that there is a $k$ such that $P(n)$ holds for all $n \geqslant k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), which is indeed false, a counterexample is $a_n=1+1/n$.

For (c), which is indeed false, a counterexample is $a_n=1-1/n$.

Comment: Yes, counterexamples are especially easy to come up with once one realizes that if a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ converges then $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)= \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)$

Comment: I just recognized my typo. For c, i meant to have $a_n\geq0$ eventually.

Comment: Consider the sequence $-1,1,-1,1,-1 \dots$

Comment: The question I have for (a) with the given counterexample is how my $limsup$ is stil $1$. I can't come up with a subsequence that makes sense there where that is still the $limsup$

Comment: What is your definition of limsup?

Comment: OK, I sort of get it . $\alpha$ is a subsequential limit point of ${a_n}$ iff there is a subsequence that converges to $\alpha$. My confusion arises from the idea that does this work because $1$ is the only thing that the c.ex. converges to?